Finding all integral points of an equation $x^2+3y^2=784$
Given a curve $C$, defined by the equation $x^2 + 3y^2 = 784$, find all the integral points on that curve, i.e. points $(m,n$) such that $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$.
How do you do this? I tried assuming $m,n$ to be such points.
$$m^2 + 3n^2 = 784$$
$$3n^2 = 784 - m^2$$
I then conclude that $3|(784 - m^2)$ since $n^2 \in \mathbb{Z}$.
Therefore $784 - m^2 =3k, k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus, $n^2 = k$.
I have no idea how to proceed and if this approach is even valid.

These kind of problems can be solved by Alpertron Calculators ,link: https://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM

Without loss of generality $x,y\geq0$, and reducing mod $8$ shows that $x$ and $y$ are both even. Write $x=2u$ and $y=2v$ to get $u^2+3v^2=196$, and so $v\leq8$. This leaves just $8$ candidates to check, of which $5$ are indeed solutions.

First notice that the number of solutions is finite due to the $+$ sign.
So a brute force search up to $28^2=784$ will always work, yet this is tedious to do manually. So assuming you don't have a computer you want to reduce the search space to do it manually.
We can start by looking for parity:
$x^2+3y^2\equiv x^2+y^2\equiv x+y\equiv 784\equiv 0\pmod 2$
Therefore $x$ and $y$ have the same parity (i.e. $0,0$ or $1,1$ only sum to $0$ modulo $2$)

We can show they cannot both be odd

$\begin{cases}x=2n+1\\y=2p+1\end{cases}\quad$ reduces to $\underbrace{n(n+1)}_\text{even}+3\underbrace{p(p+1)}_\text{even}=\underbrace{195}_\text{odd}\quad$ impossible

So let examine the even case

$\begin{cases}x=2n\\y=2p\end{cases}\quad$ reduces to $n^2+3p^2=196$
This means that $p^2=\frac{196-n^2}3\le \frac{196}3\le 66$
So $0\le p\le 8$ and we have reduced our search to only $9$ tries.
This is sufficiently small numbers to do the calculation manually:
$\begin{array} {c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
p & p^2 & 3p^2 & 196-3p^2 & n & x & y\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 196 & 14 & 28 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 3 & 193 &  &  & \\
2 & 4 & 12 & 184 &  &  & \\
3 & 9 & 27 & 169 & 13 & 26 & 6\\
4 & 16 & 48 & 148 &  &  & \\
5 & 25 & 75 & 121 & 11 & 22 & 10\\
6 & 36 & 108 & 88 &   &  & \\
7 & 49 & 147 & 49 & 7 & 14 & 14\\
8 & 64 & 192 & 4 & 2 & 4 & 16
\end{array}$
Of course you need to consider all four $\pm x,\pm y$ possibilities for solutions in $\mathbb Z$ since the squares are just cancelling the signs.

I'm afraid that, from here on, you'll on the try-and-error track :-)
I have created an Excel file, having the value for $m$ going from $1$ up to $28$ and calculate $784-m^2$, the square root of that number on three, and then the fractional part (is it zero or not?).
This is what I get:

Remark: I used a trick in order to calculate the fractional part of a number. That trick can be seen in cell "E5".
I admit: when $m$ can be divided by $3$ you can't have a solution, but that does not give enough information.
